# Simple condition in a Math expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any simple math expression that returns $-1$ if $x > a$ or $1$ if $x < a$?

Comment: What if $x=a$??

Comment: It can either be undefined at x = a, or -1 or 1. Doesn't matter to me.

Comment: Is $\dfrac{a-x}{\lvert a-x\rvert}$ to your liking?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert Daniel Fischer's perfectly good comment-answer into an actual answer: $$\frac{a-x}{|a-x|}$$

Comment: Hey, that's not true. I do that a lot. I just can't keep up with them all.

Comment: Fair enough. It always strikes me that you (and David Mitra) leave a whole bunch of comment-answers, but I haven't seen many of your actual answers.

Comment: Odd. Our primary tags have  a fair amount of overlap.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest I know is $$f(x)= \begin {cases} 1 &x \lt a\\-1&x\gt a \end {cases}$$ This is a fine expression